# Spark 1.6 Pearson correlation

Tags: apache-spark

Spark 1.6

If I have a dataset and I want to identifiy the features in a dataset with the greatest predictive power by using Pearson correlation which tools should I use?

The naive approach I used... was:

```
val columns = x.columns.toList.filterNot(List("id","maxcykle","rul") contains)
val corrVithRul = columns.map( c =>  (c,x.stat.corr("rul", c, "pearson")) )

Output:

    columns: List[String] = List(cykle, setting1, setting2, setting3, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9, s10, s11, s12, s13, s14, s15, s16, s17, s18, s19, s20, s21, label1, label2, a1, sd1, a2, sd2, a3, sd3, a4, sd4, a5, sd5, a6, sd6, a7, sd7, a8, sd8, a9, sd9, a10, sd10, a11, sd11, a12, sd12, a13, sd13, a14, sd14, a15, sd15, a16, sd16, a17, sd17, a18, sd18, a19, sd19, a20, sd20, a21, sd21)
    corrVithRul: List[(String, Double)] = List((cykle,-0.7362405993070199), (setting1,-0.0031984575547410617), (setting2,-0.001947628351500473), (setting3,NaN), (s1,-0.011460304217886725), (s2,-0.6064839743782909), (s3,-0.5845203909175897), (s4,-0.6789482333860454), (s5,-0.011121400898477964), (s6,-0.1283484484732187), (s7,0.6572226620548292), (s8,-0.5639684065744165), (s9,-0.3901015749180319), (s10,-0.04924720421765515), (s11,-0.6962281014554186), (s12,0.6719831036132922), (s13,-0.5625688251505582), (s14,-0.30676887025759053), (s15,-0.6426670441973734), (s16,-0.09716223410021836), (s17,-0.6061535537829589), (s18,NaN), (s19,NaN), (s20,0.6294284994377392), (s21,0.6356620421802835), (label1,-0.5665958821050425), (label2,-0.548191636440298), (a1,0.040592887198906136), (sd1,NaN), (a2,-0.7364292...
```

Which of course is submitting one job per map iteration, Statistics.corr might be what I am looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Statistics.corr` looks like correct choice here. Another options you may consider are `RowMatrix.columnSimilarities` (cosine similarities between columns, optionally with optimized version which uses sampling with threshold) and `RowMatrix.computeCovariance`. One way or another you'll have to assemble your data into `Vectors` first. Assuming columns are already of `DoubleType` you can use `VectorAssembler`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector

val df: DataFrame = ??? 

val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(df.columns.diff(Seq("id","maxcykle","rul")))
  .setOutputCol("features")

val rows = assembler.transform(df)
  .select($"features")
  .rdd
  .map(_.getAs[Vector]("features"))
```

Next you can use `Statistics.corr`

```scala
import org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.Statistics

Statistics.corr(rows)
```

or convert to `RowMatrix`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix

val mat = new RowMatrix(rows)

mat.columnSimilarities(0.75)
```

Comment: I dont know how to interpit the matrix from S.corr, if column "x"  is my  predictor/target column

Comment: Unfortunately you'll have to go by index so it useful to put dependent variable first. Otherwise it is just a correlation matrix as you can expect.

Comment: should probably normalize before correlation also?

Comment: For correlation? Not really.

Comment: yes, I see that  I get the same results. 

Found the following formatting tips for Matrix in python, looks like there is no great way of doing the same in Scala 
https://www.codementor.io/spark/tutorial/mllib-basic-statistics-exploratory-data-analysis