# Spark: Computing correlations of a DataFrame with missing values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I currently have a DataFrame of doubles with approximately 20% of the data being null values. I want to calculate the Pearson correlation of one column with every other column and return the columnId's of the top 10 columns in the DataFrame.

I want to filter out nulls using pairwise deletion, similar to R's pairwise.complete.obs option in its Pearson correlation function. That is, if one of the two vectors in any correlation calculation has a null at an index, I want to remove that row from both vectors.

I currently do the following:

```
val df = ... //my DataFrame
val cols = df.columns
df.registerTempTable("dataset")
val target = "Row1"
val mapped = cols.map {colId => 
    val results = sqlContext.sql(s"SELECT ${target}, ${colId} FROM dataset WHERE (${colId} IS NOT NULL AND ${target} IS NOT NULL)")
    (results.stat.corr(colId, target) , colId)
  }.sortWith(_._1 > _._1).take(11).map(_._2)
```

This runs very slowly, as every single map iteration is its own job. Is there a way to do this efficiently, perhaps using Statistics.corr in the Mllib, as per [this SO Question (Spark 1.6 Pearson Correlation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35849435/spark-1-6-pearson-correlation)

Comment: spark by default handles this it drops all the rows with null values when you calculate correlation

Answer (score 1):

There are "na" functions on `DataFrame`: [`DataFrameNaFunctions` API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions)
They work in the same way `DataFramStatFunctions` do.
You can drop the rows containing a null in either of your two dataframe columns with the following syntax:

```
myDataFrame.na.drop("any", target, colId)
```

if you want to drop rows containing null any of the columns then it is:
    myDataFrame.na.drop("any")

By limiting the dataframe to the two columns you care about first, you can use the second method and avoid verbose!

As such your code would become:

```
val df = ??? //my DataFrame
val cols = df.columns
val target = "Row1"
val mapped = cols.map {colId => 
    val resultDF = df.select(target, colId).na.drop("any")
    (resultDF.stat.corr(target, colId) , colId)
  }.sortWith(_._1 > _._1).take(11).map(_._2)
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tristan! While DataFrameNaFunctions improves the readability of my code, it doesn't provide the speedup that I've been looking for. Currently, I'm iterating over a distributed DataFrame (df) using a non-distributed data source (cols). Ideally, I want to use a transformation on my DataFrame that maps a columnId to a correlation value in order to maximize parallelization